# Creating Closed Counter for Cases?

Tags: apex, trigger, case, formula-field, case-object

Editing a Closed Case will automatically change its status from 'Closed' to 'Pending' and then when the edits are saved, the Case is then 'Closed' again.

I would like to create a Counter that counts how many times the Case is 'Closed', potentially using the 'Closed' Checkbox data type.

I am open to writing an Apex trigger, but would appreciate some insight on a way to just use standard formulas if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a pretty simple workflow rule.

**Criteria**

- `IsClosed = true`
- Evaluate the rule when a record is: created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria

[image: WFR Criteria]

**Action**

- Field Update (Field = Closed Counter)
- Formula: `IF(ISNULL(Closed_Counter__c), 1, Closed_Counter__c + 1)`

Comment: Thanks! I actually went back and tried a version of this. WFR: created and every time edited( ISCHANGED(CloseDate)), Field Updater:(Closed_Counter_Field_Updater__c + 1) and that doesn't seem to be successfully updating the number field

Comment: I know this is slightly different than your solution, but the similiarites are close enough to make me wonder if I am missing a key piece of linking the Workflow together

Comment: The field name is actually `ClosedDate`. Is that a typo? Otherwise, perhaps the Case is not actually reopening and closing? Does the `ClosedDate` actually change?

Comment: that was a typo on my end, it seems that the ClosedDate is actually changing if the Record is edited and saved a certain way, but it's still not triggering the Field Update, and I made sure the WFR is active and linked to the Field Updater. I will try your solution

Comment: It looks like you didn't include the `ISNULL` check. Is the value being initialized to `0`?

Comment: Let's [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32822/discussion-between-adrian-and-gpp) about it? I think your criterion makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

A formula field isn't the right tool for the job here. You could probably make it work through some convoluted means, but what you're looking for here is a Workflow rule (and field update).

Something along the lines of

```
ISCHANGED(Status) && ISPICKVAL(Status, 'Closed')
```

The field update would simply increment a number field (which you would need to create if you haven't already), and you'd be on your merry way.